# Can't write to dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make an automatically updating range on an excel sheet with multiple tables.

I have

```
Dim datarange as Range
Dim dataend as Integer
dataend = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Set datarange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(8, dataend))
```

This is to update the range for a chart on another sheet.

When I print `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` in the immediate window it returns the number 7, so I know that it is counting the rows.  But when I try to run the code I get an error saying "Application defined or object defined error."  I don't know why the Cells property won't take the value of the `dataend` variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Cells()` without a qualifying worksheet reference it defaults to the active sheet, so you need to qualify both your references to make sure they point to Sheet2:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set datarange = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(8, dataend))
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You input `Cell`, means the active sheet.

You can use

```
Set datarange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(8, dataend)
```

to get the range.

But the representation is too long. So you may simplify it by using `with ... end with`, like @Tim Williams write in the answer:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set datarange = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(8, dataend))
End With
```

It means the same.

Comment: Exact copy of @TimWilliams ' answer from 3 hours ago?

Comment: Actually, I opened a excel and input the VBA code myself, I also used range function instead of cell function, but I have some issue to do so I didnot input the answer right after. And I think my answer did explain work to this problem, not just copy. The answer is totally the same. I will add @ then.